# Determining an Equation from Some Given Information

Tags: geometry

$AB$ contains points $A(-6, -1)$ and $B(1, 4)$. $CD$ contains point $D(7, 2)$. $ABC=BCD$ and $m ABC = 90$. What is an equation of $CD$?

So far, I've graphed all the given points, $A,B$ and $D$, but I don't know where to go from there. I know I'm supposed to find $C$, I just don't understand how.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do ABC=BCD amd m ABC=90 mean?

Comment: Hi! ABC and BCD are both angles that are congruent to each other,  angle ABC is equal to 90 so angle BCD must also be congruent to 90

Comment: In other words, ABCD is a right trapezium?

Comment: If $ABC = 90$ then $C$ is in the perpendicular to $AB$ that contains $B$. Also $C$ is in the parallel to $AB$ that contains $D$ since $ABC=BCD$, so the intersection of this two lines is your answer.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Compute the slope $m$ of $(CD)$, which is also the slope of $(AB)$.  Line $(CD)$  is the line with slope $m$ passing though $D=(7,2)$. You have a formula to get its equation.

Comment: alright the slope of both would be 5/7 right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: alright I came out with a point of (0,-3) however it doesn't back up the point that mABC and mBCD are both equal to 90

Comment: Do you want a point or an equation of a line?

Comment: ahhhh your right I just need the equation, thank you!